# jQuery slider - plugin needed

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, slider

I am looking for a slider which has two types of functionalities

1. should be able to display a N number of slides like the image below.. which shows 5 at once.

[image]

2. The regular slider where only one image is displayed at a time..
   [image]

Comment: and none of these (http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/) fits what you want ? Especially Pikachoose, which looks like what you are looking for

Comment: Think you are looking for some slider / scroller like in google books homepage..

Comment: It's more a slideshow than a slider i think you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible with coda slider.

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/slider-gallery.html

Answer (score 1):

I think for the first one, if you want to make something interactive, you can use [Flow Slider jQuery plugin](http://www.flowslider.com).